# Go to next page on showthread.php with scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy. For about 4 days I'm stuck at go to next page when fetching showthread.php (forum based on vbulletin).

My target: http://forum.femaledaily.com/showthread.php?359-Hair-Smoothing

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from femaledaily.items import FemaledailyItem

class Femaledaily(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "femaledaily"
    allowed_domains = ["femaledaily.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page2",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page3",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page4",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for thd in response.css("tbody > tr "):
            print "==========NEW THREAD======"
            url = thd.xpath('.//div[@class="threadlist-title"]/a/@href').extract()
            url[0] = "http://forum.femaledaily.com/"+url[0]
            print url[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url[0], callback=self.parse_thread)

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        for page in response.xpath('//ol[@id="posts"]/li'):
            item = FemaledailyItem()
            item['thread_title'] = response.selector.xpath('//span[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            # item['thread_starter'] = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="username_container"]/a/text()').extract_first()
            post_creator = page.xpath('.//div[@class="username_container"]/a/text()').extract()

            if not post_creator:
                item['post_creator'] = page.xpath('.//div[@class="username_container"]/a/span/text()').extract()
            else:
                item['post_creator'] = post_creator

            item['post_content'] = ""

            cot = page.xpath(".//blockquote[@class='postcontent restore ']/text()").extract()
            for ct in cot:
                item['post_content'] += ct.replace('\t','').replace('\n','')

            yield item
```

I'm able to get first 10 posts for every thread, but I'm confused how to go to next page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change made in your code so that it will paginate properly,

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from femaledaily.items import FemaledailyItem

class Femaledaily(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "femaledaily"
    allowed_domains = ["femaledaily.com"]
    BASE_URL = "http://forum.femaledaily.com/"
    start_urls = [
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page2",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page3",
        "http://forum.femaledaily.com/forumdisplay.php?136-Hair-Care/page4",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for thd in response.css("tbody > tr "):
            print "==========NEW THREAD======"
            url = thd.xpath('.//div[@class="threadlist-title"]/a/@href').extract()
            url = "http://forum.femaledaily.com/"+url[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_thread)

        # pagination
        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="prev_next"]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            yield Request(self.BASE_URL  + next_page[0], callback=self.parse)
        else:
            return

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        for page in response.xpath('//ol[@id="posts"]/li'):
            item = FemaledailyItem()
            item['thread_title'] = response.selector.xpath('//span[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            # item['thread_starter'] = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="username_container"]/a/text()').extract_first()
            post_creator = page.xpath('.//div[@class="username_container"]/a/text()').extract()

            if not post_creator:
                item['post_creator'] = page.xpath('.//div[@class="username_container"]/a/span/text()').extract()
            else:
                item['post_creator'] = post_creator

            item['post_content'] = ""

            cot = page.xpath(".//blockquote[@class='postcontent restore ']/text()").extract()
            for ct in cot:
                item['post_content'] += ct.replace('\t','').replace('\n','')

            yield item

        # pagination   
        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="prev_next"]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            yield Request(self.BASE_URL  + next_page[0], callback=self.parse_thread)
        else:
            return
```

Here first extract the next page's link (ie, single forward arrow) and giving a request to that `next_page_url` and make the callback function as the same function from where it is called. When it reaches the last page the `next-page-url` vanishes and halts.